# Recurrence relation for Gegenbauer/ultrashperical polynomials

Tags: discrete-mathematics, polynomials, recurrence-relations

For a non-negative integer $k$ define the Gegenbauer polynomial of degree $k$ for $S^{n-1}$ by $C_{0}(x) = 1$, $C_{1}(x) = (n-2) \, x$, and
$$C_{k}(x) = \sum_{i=0}^{\lfloor k/2 \rfloor} \frac{(-1)^i \, \Pi_{j=0}^{k-i-1}(n+2j-2)}{2^i \, i! \, (k-2i)!} \, x^{k-2i}, $$
for $k \ge 2$.
How can I show that
$$(k+1)C_{k+1}(x) = (n+2k-2)xC_k(x) - (n+k-3)C_{k-1}(x) \quad ?$$

Apparently it is a straightforward computation but I'm not getting anywhere just using the definition.

Comment: You might have to consider even and odd k separately.

Comment: @martycohen I tried that starting on right hand side and then do an index shift but I'm really not seeing how I can reach the left hand side.

Answer (score 1):

First it should be noted that the function, given by the series, is
$$ C_{k}^{\frac{n}{2}-1}(x).$$
This has the hypergeometric form
$$ C_{k}^{\frac{n}{2}-1}(x) = \frac{\left(\frac{n}{2}-1\right)_{k}}{k!} \, (2 x)^{k} \, {}_{2}F_{1}\left( - \frac{k}{2} \, \frac{1-k}{2}; \, 2 - \frac{n}{2} - k; \, \frac{1}{x^2} \right). $$
One way, at this point, is to use relations known for the hypergeometric function to obtain the correct relation desired. The fastest way is to use the known Gegenbauer relation
$$ n \, C_{n}^{\nu}(x) = 2 \, (n + \nu -1) \, x \, C_{n-1}^{v}(x) - (n + 2 \nu -2) \, C_{n-2}^{\nu}(x). $$
This gives the relation
$$ k \, C_{k}^{\frac{n}{2}-1}(x) = (2 k + n - 4) \, x \, C_{k-1}^{\frac{n}{2}-1}(x) - (k + n - 4) \, C_{k-2}^{\frac{n}{2}-1}(x). $$